# How to calculate/then display/change the css colour of the box displaying the value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, math

Basically I have a form which right now has 2 drop downs with weights to each item.

I need on the page for a total value to be calculated based off the weights from the drop downs.

This would be displayed in a box which would change colour based on how high the value gets.

For example drop down 1 would be Item1 = One, weight = 1 Item2 = Two, weight = 2 etc etc.

The math would be (drop down 1's selected item weight) * (drop down 2's selected item weight).

Each drop down would have only 5 items with weights from 1-5.

Right now I have 2 tables storing the data regarding the 2 drop downs, if it's easier to do it another was to produce the end result easier then I'll go for that.

I'll try and update tomorrow this topic with the experiments I've done so far but if anybody has any ideas I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, what about something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/rkWDR/6/)?

The idea is to attach a `change` event to your `select` elements (you may need to change the selector to be more specific if you have more on your page). In the event handler, we get the value of the 2 `select` elements in question, multiply them, and write the result to a `div`. The background colour of the `div` is then changed depending on what the total value was.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to call the javascript after page load so I'm seeing if I can do an in line onselect with my drop downs based off your code but I don't have much confidence I'll get it to work.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't seem to call after page load"? Try putting the code I gave you inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` block.

Comment: I'd forgotten to move the closing tag down for document.ready, new issue discovered which is it doesn't like the select lists being inside a table and will result in NaN being displayed when you select a item on the select along with the final colour "else if (total <= 14) {
                $("#total").css("backgroundColor", "#EEEF86");
            }
            else {
                $("#total").css("backgroundColor", "#FF7F7F");
            }"

Comment: found out what the problem was, at some point it had renamed one of the selects to a different id which was what was breaking it, now I just have to figure out how to either tie these 2 selects to there corresponding model/table values or connect the DropDownListFor's to the math.

Comment: <select id="ex1" name="ex1"> in view, ra.ex1 = Convert.ToInt32(fc["ex1"]); in controller oh yeh and in [HttpPost]public ActionResult Create ([viewmodel name+assignment], FormCollection fc) gave the table the assignment of ra hence ra.ex1 =  and this was how I pointed it back to table/model/database.  Figured I'd add this in so someone else could look at this topic and it would cover from start to finish and thx for your help james with jquery.

Comment: tiny issue, I've created like 10 variables name l1-5 and i1-5 and for the 1st set done var ex1value = parseInt($("#ex1").val());
$("#ex1value").text(ex1value);
if ((parseInt($("#ex1").val())) = 1) {
    $("#lscoredesc").text(l1);
if ((parseInt($("#ex1").val())) = 2) {
    $("#lscoredesc").text(l2);
if ((parseInt($("#ex1").val())) = 3) {
    $("#lscoredesc").text(l3);
if ((parseInt($("#ex1").val())) = 4) {
//                $("#lscoredesc").text(l4);
if ((parseInt($("#ex1").val())) = 5) {
    $("#lscoredesc").text(l5);

Comment: at 1st I tried "if ( ex1value = 1)" but that didn't work either and no matter what I try it just breaks the javascript if I have those if statements in there.  I'm basically trying to have a 2nd div which will display additional text below the selects and the additional text is the var l1-5 and i1-5.

Comment: nm found out I forgot to put the 2nd } on each if and I needed to make it == and not just =

Comment: I do still have 1 question, how do I assign a var in jquery a model value for example (<%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RaSub.Total)%>) tried "var total = parseInt($("#RaSub.Total").val());" and "var total = parseInt($("RaSub.Total").val());" and "var total = $("#RaSub.Total").val();" and "var total = $("RaSub.Total").val();"    so any ideas? (since I'm off work tomoz I prob won't see your reply till monday)

Comment: I guess you don't want to answer